# Why do I need brackets on this nullary function in this Scala expression?

Tags: scala, syntax, dsl

This **doesn't compile** with Scala 2.7.7.final or 2.8.0.final for me:

```
new FileInputStream("test.txt") getChannel transferTo(
    0, Long.MaxValue, new FileOutputStream("test-copy.txt") getChannel)
```

This **does compile** with Scala 2.7.7.final and 2.8.0.final for me:

```
new FileInputStream("test.txt") getChannel() transferTo(
    0, Long.MaxValue, new FileOutputStream("test-copy.txt") getChannel)
```

Why is it that I need to do `getChannel()` instead of just `getChannel` here?

Comment: Assuming you're using Java FileIn/OutputStreams, even the second example does not compile here because the arguments to `transferTo` are out of order.  Did you mean to place the FileOutputStream's chanel at the tail of `transferTo`'s argument list instead of the head?  That does compile here.

Comment: Thank you Dan.  I have fixed the code in my question.  This is a case of code in my editor versus code in my pasteboard.  I will be more careful with code I post in future :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is really simple. If you are using spaces instead of .'s to chain method calls then:

```
 a b c d     //is parsed as a call to
 (a.b(c))(d)
```

In your case the last two parameters are being called like (because `d` is more than one parameter, `d`, `e` and `f` say):

```
a b c(d, e, f)    //is parsed as a call to
a.b(c(d, e, f))
```

i.e. the same as the first case. However, you want the call to be:

```
(a b).c(d, e, f)
```

Which is not the same!

- `a = new FileInputStream("test.txt")`
- `b = getChannel`
- `c = transferTo`
- `d = new FileOutputStream("test-copy.txt") getChannel`
- `e = 0`
- `f = Long.MaxValue`

This has not changed between 2.7 and 2.8 as far as I'm aware!

Comment: Thank you oxbox_lakes, the 2.7/2.8 point is accurate.  I retested the two cases in 2.7.7.final and 2.8.0.final and found the behavior to be the same.  I have amended my question to reflect that and limit confusion.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the parsing is `a.b(c(d, e, f))` -- ie, `apply` inference on objects (parameters) before operator resolution.

Comment: Apols for the mistake Daniel - fixed now

Answer (score 6):

The general rule is that the compiler interprets strings like

```
new FileInputStream("test.txt") getChannel transferTo(...)
```

as

```
object method parameter method parameter method parameter
```

so in your case, that means

```
new FileInputStream("test.txt")    // object
getChannel                         // method
transferTo(...)                    // parameter
```

so the compiler tries to call `transferTo` as a free function so it can pass its result as a parameter to getChannel. When you add the parentheses, you get

```
new FileInputStream("test.txt") getChannel() transferTo(...)

new FileInputStream("test.txt")    // object
getChannel                         // method
()                                 // parameter (empty parameter list)
transferTo                         // method
(...)                              // parameter
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe because it's not clear to the compiler how to divide the tokens up. Is it `new FileInputStream("test.txt")(getChannel, transferTo(...))`? `new (FileInputStream("test.txt"), getChannel, transferTo(...))`? `(new FileInputStream("test.txt")).getChannel(transferTo(...))`? The compiler doesn't have enough information to know that `transferTo` is a property of the object returned by `getChannel`.

For maximum clarity you'd have something like:

```
(new FileInputStream("test.txt")).getChannel().transferTo(
  (new FileOutputStream("test-copy.txt")).getChannel(), 0, Long.MaxValue)
```